# How to find entire string using typeORM, Nestjs, SQL Server, just like LIKE clause in mysql

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm, sql-like, qsqlquery

I have database called `Beta` and table called `Keys`. In that table I have a column `licenseKey: string`. I want to find the entire `licenseKey` from the portion of `licenseKey`.

Just like SQL below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM KEYS 
WHERE licenseKey LIKE "%XYZ%"
```

I have following code in my controller file:

```
        @Get('getByLicenseKey/:licenseKey')
   async getByLicenseKey(@Param('licenseKey') licenseKey: string) {
        console.log('dsaadfad');
        return this.licenseKeyService.getKeyByLicenseKey(licenseKey);
    }
```

Service file

```
async getKeyByLicenseKey(licenseKey: string): Promise<keys[]> {
        return await this.keyRepo.find({ licenseKey: Like(`${licenseKey}`) });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
async getKeyByLicenseKey(licenseKey: string): Promise<keys[]> {
    return this.keyRepo.find({
        where:{licenseKey: Like(`%${licenseKey}%`)}
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you using `%` in query? What does `%` mean?

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM provides out of the box **Like** function. Example from [their docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md):

To perform a partial string search using TypeORM with NestJS and SQL Server, you can utilize the Like operator provided by TypeORM. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import { Like } from 'typeorm';

async getKeyByLicenseKey(licenseKey: string): Promise<Key[]> {
  return await this.keyRepo.find({ licenseKey: Like(`%${licenseKey}%`) });
}
```

Make sure you import the Like operator from TypeORM. In the service file, you can use the Like operator with the % wildcard to search for the licenseKey value within the column. This will retrieve all records from the Keys table where the licenseKey column contains the specified licenseKey value as a substring.